# Two graphs on R with distinct values

Tags: r, graphics

Is there a way to plot 2 data frames on R despite that they have different values?. For example:

```
data1
[hour]   [value] 
1          5
2          4
3          3
4          4

data2
[hour]   [value]
1          4
2          8
4          9
5          2
```

I would like to paint in the x axis 1,2,3,4,5 and in the y axis the value it correspond.

Thanks :)

Comment: you might be looking for xlim and ylim arguments to `plot`. See their entries in `?par`.

Comment: `plot(data2, type="l", col="red");lines(data1, col="blue")`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
plot(data1, type="l", xlim = c(0,6), ylim = c(0,10))
lines(data2)
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It paints the value 9 on 3 and 2 on 4 (5 dissapear)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add three lines of codes as below.

```
   plot(data2$hour,data2$value,xlab='hour',ylab='value')
   par(new=TRUE)
   points(data1$hour,data1$value)
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way.

```
library(ggplot2)
data1 <- data.frame(hour=c(1,2,3,4),value=c(5,4,3,4))
data2 <- data.frame(hour=c(1,2,4,5),value=c(4,8,9,2))
data3 <- rbind(data1,data2)
data3$data <- c(rep("data1",4),rep("data2",4))

#try this
ggplot(data3,aes(x=hour,y=value))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~data)+
  theme_bw()
```

[image: fig1]

Here is another way (with colours and lines):

```
#or this
ggplot(data3,aes(x=hour,y=value,col=data))+
 geom_point()+
 geom_line()+
 theme_bw()
```

[image: fig2]

Answer (score 0):

We can use:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
```

By using this, we can have two different dataframe individually on same row.